# Why does Microsoft tie .NET runtime versions to specific versions of VIsual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

Why is it that I have to upgrade to VS 2010 to build/run .NET4 projects?  This seems somewhat ridiculous to me.  Why should the run-time that my code runs against, or the compiler that the IDE invokes (hopefully) generically through MSBUILD rules have anything to do with the IDE I am using?

Comment: "Please update your version of GVIM so that you can run the latest version of GCC".  Unix programmers would LAUGH if the GCC team suggested this.

Comment: Your rant poorly disguised as a question demonstrates either a fundamental lack of technical savvy or a desire for confrontation. Either way the petulant nature of the question is offensive.

Comment: when you can deploy a client server data driven app in 15 minutes with GCC then come back and ask again.

Comment: There are other IDEs - if you don't like it, you could always vote with your feet...

Comment: @paddy - yeah there are other IDE but, say what you will about microsoft, VS is the Bentley of IDEs. <-- from experience. (not implying that you are implying, just sayin...)

Comment: Actually, my question is posed because I want to use .NET 4.0 text rendering, but NOT a new IDE. I do not want to change the structure of my csproj files, and I do not want to install VS 2010 on the desktops of all of our WPF developers, etc.  This is a huge amount of effort just so that I can link against a different set of runtime libraries with a code-base that otherwise works fine with the old tools.

Comment: @Armentage- That's how Microsoft sells these expensive tools.

Answer (score 4):

There's usually a way to get it working with older VS versions. I know I was compiling WCF projects (3.5) on VS2005 before we upgraded to VS2008. You just have to set up the references by hand (and possibly change the MSBuild project file), and of course you lose out on the actual IDE enhancements (I wouldn't want to have done *WPF* on VS2005...)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe because .Net 4.0 was vaporware when VS2008 was released so support for it was never baked in?

Maybe because MS is a company that needs to sell products to make money, they can't sell new licences if they just update old versions of the product?

Maybe because old versions of the product (VS2008) would take too much retooling to *natively* support .Net 4.0?

These are just random thoughts that may or may not help you with your current issue, which seems more like a rant than an issue?

Comment: heheh - you said 'tool'. That is it on the money - tooling.

Comment: Are these questions or statements?

Comment: The question may be a bit of a rant, but this answer is pretty unhelpful and uninsightful in my opinion.

Comment: @coxymla - i wouldn't say it is *unhelpful*, how can anyone give an authoritive answer on this question? The most any of us can do is speculate. What i am pointing out is that the reasons are probably all based on business decisions, but as i don't work in the corporate or project management structure of MS i can only offer educated speculation from the viewpoint of an observer. To fully answer the OP's question would probably take half a book.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft are a business. They develop new products using money made from selling existing products.